# multiple grouping based on if key exists or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got following model `reportcharities`, with this sample data:

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d79b93b591243962fa0c5"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dee2e536c3a72543518a0fa"),
    "charityId" : ObjectId("5dce381401a0171c50989d65"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T08:20:09.965Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T08:20:09.965Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d7afd3b591243962fa0c6"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dee2e536c3a72543518a0fa"),
    "eventId" : ObjectId("5df1ea1efe164a3c9ef854df"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T08:25:33.169Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T08:25:33.169Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d7b2c3b591243962fa0c7"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5dee2e536c3a72543518a0fa"),
    "projectId" : ObjectId("5df73c88bc67dc3b60a542fc"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T08:26:20.551Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T08:26:20.551Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dad44121cc1481303fb4d"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5e1d8c4d3b591243962fa0d0"),
    "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:00:04.231Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:00:04.231Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dad7c121cc1481303fb4e"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5e1d8c4d3b591243962fa0d0"),
    "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:01:00.322Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:01:00.322Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dad8b121cc1481303fb4f"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5e1d8c4d3b591243962fa0d0"),
    "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:01:15.181Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:01:15.181Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dada9121cc1481303fb50"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5e1d8c4d3b591243962fa0d0"),
    "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:01:45.433Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-14T12:01:45.433Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1eb08ecaa8076b22547abc"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5e1e9d5744b39654f05ed8b4"),
    "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-15T06:26:22.999Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-15T06:26:22.999Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here user as `userId` can report either a charity as `charityId`, project as `projectId` or event as `eventId` at one time.

Now I need to find counts of each category as group and their counts as total reportings by users. For example for each of the these "types" I'm suppose to get the following count:

```
  "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf"), count: 5
 "projectId" : ObjectId("5df73c88bc67dc3b60a542fc"), count: 1
 "charityId" : ObjectId("5dce381401a0171c50989d65") count: 1
"eventId" : ObjectId("5df1ea1efe164a3c9ef854df") count: 1
```

... etc etc.

Only one of `charityId`,`projectId` or `eventId` exists in document, I couldn't implement multiple grouping in aggregation.

Comment: tom slabbaert thanks for edit Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reconstruct the data a little bit, using this following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "data": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": {
                        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
                    },
                    "as": "datum",
                    "cond": {
                        "$in": [
                            "$$datum.k",
                            [
                                "eventId",
                                "projectId",
                                "charityId"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$data"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "key": "$data.k",
                "value": "$data.v"
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1.0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "type": "$_id.key",
            "count": "$count",
            "_id": "$_id.value"
        }
    }
]);
```

Will give you this output:

```
{ 
    "type" : "projectId", 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df73c88bc67dc3b60a542fc")
}
{ 
    "type" : "eventId", 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df1ea1efe164a3c9ef854df")
}
{ 
    "type" : "charityId", 
    "count" : 1.0, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dce381401a0171c50989d65")
}
{ 
    "type" : "eventId", 
    "count" : 5.0, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf")
}
```

Comment: Again this is just a quick example of data structure manipulation, i'm sure you can find a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: yeah sure will do. Thank you very much ,sir

Answer (score 1):

This aggregation uses `$facet` - the output format is little different.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
 { 
      $facet: {
          charity: [
             { $match: { charityId: { $exists: true } } },
             { $group: { _id: "$charityId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
             { $project: { charityId: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0 } }
          ],
          event: [
             { $match: { eventId: { $exists: true } } },
             { $group: { _id: "$eventId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
             { $project: { eventId: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0 } }
          ],
          project: [
             { $match: { projectId: { $exists: true } } },
             { $group: { _id: "$projectId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
             { $project: { projectId: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0 } }
         ],
      } 
  },
  {
      $project: { result: { $concatArrays: [ "$charity", "$event", "$project" ] } }
  }
] )
```

The output:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "count" : 1,
                        "charityId" : ObjectId("5dce381401a0171c50989d65")
                },
                {
                        "count" : 5,
                        "eventId" : ObjectId("5e1d8bdd3b591243962fa0cf")
                },
                {
                        "count" : 1,
                        "eventId" : ObjectId("5df1ea1efe164a3c9ef854df")
                },
                {
                        "count" : 1,
                        "projectId" : ObjectId("5df73c88bc67dc3b60a542fc")
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: thanks prasad_ for providing this alternative too. thank you very much